# CSS animation for Sort not working as desired

Tags: javascript, css, sorting

I am working on Demo of bubble sort and other as well using pure Javascript (not jquery) using buttons . I need to swap buttons from current position to the location reqired. I am successful in sorting the numbers but unable to set animations as desired.

[Bubble Sort code](http://jsfiddle.net/vLDp2/)

(The desired animation here would be to translate the numbered button with the maximum value to the right on each pass.And the minimum to the left. Until the numbers are displayed in completely sorted order.Used the word "desired" since animations would be different for other sorts.)

```
 temp1.style.webkitTransform="translateX(100px)"; //only for Chrome
 temp.style.webkitTransform="translateX(-100px)";
```

Comment: where is the HTML code??

Comment: What button? i don't see any button in that fiddle.. Did you even check it? `Uncaught ReferenceError: str_array is not defined.`

Comment: That's the sorting and animation code. The input's being read through text file. Okay, Will edit the fiddle likewise.

Comment: @TilwinJoy Done that :)

Comment: "I need to swap buttons" there is only one button in that fiddle.. did you mean the numbers? 

"unable to set animations as desired" How do we know what is the **DESIRED**  animation, unless you say it..? Please the question properly with enough info...

Comment: @TilwinJoy  yes.. the buttons with numbers on it. The desired animation here would  be to translate the numbered button with the maximum value to the right on each pass.And the minimum to the left. Until the numbers are displayed in completely sorted order. Used the word "DESIRED" since animations would be different for other sorts.

Comment: @please update the info in the question  so that others reading the question will understand it...